# KeyStore Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to implements a Google Maps on my APP following the [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2), but i'm stuck on create a new KeyStore to create a new Api Key, I've read that in eclipse you can Export your APP and then you can create a new KeyStore but I don't find it on Android Studio I've tried to Build / Generate Signed APK but I'm not sure if is there the correct way...
Also I've read that I have to modify my Gradle and I put this code:

I've got 3 gradles...

```
build.gradle(Module:app)

    dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
}
```

And build.gradle(Project:ProjectName)

There I didn't put nothing.

And when I add

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

it says that the android value Cannot resolve symbol.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Joan, you are doing exporting the correct way.

You should go to Build -> Generate Signed APK

Then choose Create New ..

In the new Store Key choose a folder path and file name to store your new Key store.
Enter and confirm the password.

Under the Key section also choose an Alias name, password and confirm it, and choose a length of time for this key store to be valid - 25 years seems to be quite aceptable.

In the certificate section add at least a name , the rest does not need to be filled in.

Click OK.
(You may wish to tick the remember password box.)
Then Next.

Finally you should note the location that the APK file will be located and then click Finish.

Here is a tutorial i followed on Youtube.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qatec8l3XOI

Just be sure to note where the apk file is being saved before you finish the process.

Comment: Wow, I think I got it, but when I try to do `keytool -list -v -keystore mystore.keystore` it says : 'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file, do you know what it happens? 
Btw, I vote your answer because it answered my question :)